# Why do I have to set CC and CXX specifically for CMake/Conan to install gtest for gcc/arm?

Tags: cmake, googletest, conan

For a cross-compile project, I want to install gtest/1.11.0 via Conan for ARM. In CMake I have set the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variables to gcc/g++. CMake then makes the following call to Conan:

```bash
conan install . --build missing --settings arch=armv8 --settings arch_build=x86_64 --settings build_type=Debug --settings compiler=gcc --settings compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11 --settings compiler.version=10 --settings os=Linux --settings os_build=Linux
```

The package does not seem to be available already in this configuration, so Conan tries to build it on-demand. However, I get the error gcc is not the compiler detected by CMake, which is 'Clang'. Indeed the environment variables CC and CXX are set to to clang and clang++ respectively. When I set them to gcc and g++, the problem is gone.

My understanding is that CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER should somehow "override" CC and CXX, but that does not seem to be the case for conan packages. Is there a better way than to redefine CC and CXX in CMake?

Comment: The compiler in the profile does not reflect the compiler used, but the package ID. You should use the config to set the compiler_executables: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html#conan-cmake-toolchain-conf and https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/commands/config.html?highlight=compiler_executables. The configuration will be converted by Conan client to fit CMAKE_C_COMPILER